# Android: Accessing a function within a thread and getting the result?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

In my android service, I'm starting a new thread like this

```
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new myClassName(getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

The class is ran in a separate thread because it would otherwise block the service thread (causes timeout). That code is in the "onCreate" method, and is alive the whole time whilst the service is alive (unless it crashes, of course).

Now, I need to have a function in "myClassName" which returns a String. I've not actually created that function yet, but I'm trying to test it with a function which simply returns "hello", so let's call that function "helloFn".

```
    public String helloFn(String name) {
        return "hello "+name;
    }
```

How can I call "helloFn" which is inside the thread I just created, from my service? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class which implements `Runnable`, and call `helloFn(name)` on the instance of that class.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm trying this now - however at the moment I just keep blocking the service thread.